# como fazer uma sub-rotina na função 'e1_inserir' ,em pilhas

Tags: c, fila

Galera, NAO CONSIGO criar um sub-rotina pra função 'e1_inserir'(SEGUNDO TRECHO DE CODIGO). Essa função vai ser chamada toda vez que quiser inserir uma bebida. Nesse trecho de código que coloquei aqui, ela só esta sendo chama para a função escolhe_estera(SEGUNDO TRECHO DE CODIGO) porem nao sei como realmente chama-la

O objetivo do projeto é um algoritmo que recebe produtos por tipos de dados, e armazena os mesmos, em uma STRUCT. A questão é que esses produtos podem ir pra dois tipos de esteiras. Ou seja esses produtos vão ser reedivididos conforme a esteira , para isso criei uma strct para cada esteira.
Além disso esses dados tem der ser inseridos pelo usuário pra depois serem manipulados ...
OBS: SE PRECISAR DE MAIS IMFORMACOES É SÓ IMFORMAR

```
    void escolhe_estera(int e){
            printf("DIGITE '1' para a primeira esteira OU '2' para a 
    segunda esteira");
            scanf("%d", &e);
    if(e==1){
             // chamo as verificacoes
             int b;
       e1_insere(b)
            }
            else(e==2){
                    e1_insere(int b);
            }
       }
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
       void e1_insere(e1 *f, int b)
       {
          if(e1_lotada(f) == 1)
       {
             printf("Erro\n");
       }
       else
       {
       f -> topo++;
      
       f -> bebida[f-> topo] = b; 
                   e1_inicia (f);
                    printf("\nDigite o nome \n");
                    scanf("%s", &bebida[f->topo].nome);
                    printf("\nDigite o preco \n");
                    scanf("%f",&bebida[f->topo].preco);
                    printf("Digite o volume");
                    scanf("%f",&bebida[f->topo].volume);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funções em C seguem precedência de declaração, isto é, você não pode usar uma função que ainda não foi declarada até aquele ponto do código.

Reordene suas funções para que sigam a ordem de precedência e as dependências serão resolvidas. Evite dependências circulares (a depende de b que depende de c que depende de a), ou use arquivos de cabeçalho( .h) que contenham só as declarações (as implementações ficam no .c), e use um #include no .c

Para evitar inclusões duplicadas use uma estrutura assim no .h:

```
#ifndef MEU_ARQUIVO_H
#define MEU_ARQUIVO_H

int funca();
int funcb(int a, fload b);

#endif
```